# I've implemented my Stripe payment to be SCA Compliant but can't tell if payments are leveraging the SCA feature

Tags: stripe-payments, strong-customer-authentication

I've implemented the Stripe payment to be SCA Compliant and am using the PaymentIntent. When I look at the charges, I see the `pi_` prefix instead of the `ch_` prefix. However, it's possible I need to roll this back due to some implementation details I got wrong and I can't tell if payments will be denied for no longer supporting SCA.

Does anyone know how to see if the payments themselves **require** SCA and will be denied without it? I can't find any information in any forums or documentation and don't have a contact with Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to roll this back due to some implementation details I got wrong

I assume you'll be rolling it back to the Charges + Tokens API?

If so, any payments requiring SCA will decline with `authentication_required` decline code. If they do not, the Charge will succeed (or can still be declined based on the issuing bank's response).

What implementation mistakes did you make when you integrated?

To make an SCA compliant integration on Stripe, you have two major options:

- Use Stripe Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web
- Use PaymentIntents, where you create the PaymentIntent on your server and confirm it on your client-side app/page: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements